# Layer name in OpenLayers 3.0

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

I'm looping through all the layers in my map using

```
map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer, i) {
   ...
});
```

I'd like to get the name of each layer but I haven't been able to find anything in the examples or the documentation. Any pointers?

I'm using OpenLayers 3.0.0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`name` is just a property you can set on your layer. All constructor options which are not part of the API [1] are treated as property[2].

You can later get it with `layer.get('name')` (& set it with `layer.set('name', 'foobar')`)

- 1: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.layer.Layer.html
- 2:`property` of `ol.Object`
  http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.Object.html