# Multiple tooltip Openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, tooltip

I would like to have a tooltip for each of my layers based on their display which is done by a checkbox.

I started a function with a condition depending on the layer but I have the error "layer is not defined".
How can I declare a variable that retrieves the name of my layers to be able to filter for the tooltips next?

```js
function displayTooltip(evt) {  
    var pixel = evt.pixel;  
    var map = $('#map').data('map');    
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel,
     function(feature, layer) {         
       return feature; 
        });

    var tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');

    var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
       element: tooltip,
        offset: [0, 0],
        positioning: 'bottom-left'

    });

    map.addOverlay(overlay);

    tooltip.style.display = feature ? '' : 'none';

    if (layer ===  missionsEAU | missionsEAU2) {
        overlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
        tooltip.innerHTML = feature.getProperties().DOCUMENT_QUOTE;

    } else if(layer ===  scot_admin){
        overlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
        tooltip.innerHTML = feature.getProperties().SCOT_2016;

    } else if(layer ===  epci_admin){
        overlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
        tooltip.innerHTML = feature.getProperties().EPCI_LATEST;

    } else if(layer ===  commune_admin){
        overlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
        tooltip.innerHTML = feature.getProperties().NOM_COMMUNE_LATEST;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the variable layer is in scope of another function. Here:

```
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel,
 function(feature, layer) {         
   return feature; 
    });
```

You get only the feature from that function, you can get both of it for example like this:

```
var arr = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel,
 function(feature, layer) {         
   return [feature,layer]; 
    });
var feature = arr[0];
var layer = arr[1];
```

If you want to name your layer, it is described for example [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113346/layer-name-in-openlayers-3-0/113474):